# Automapper, CustomMapping not loading fields of a virtual property

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I have the following classes.

```
 public class SomeModel
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string UserId { get; set; }
            public virtual User User { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Name { get; set; }  
        }
```

And:

```
public class SomeModelDetailsResponseModel : IMapFrom<SomeModel>, IHaveCustomMappings
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public void CreateMappings(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            configuration.CreateMap<SomeModel, SomeModelDetailsResponseModel>("name").AfterMap((b, r) =>
            {
                r.UserName = b.User.FirstName + b.User.LastName;
            });
        }
    }
```

For some reason, when I project an `IQueryable` of `SomeModel` to an `IQueryable` of `SomeModelDetailsResponseModel` the `UserName` property turns out to be `null`.

Comment: Can you show the query with the projection?

Comment: I have a simple SomeQueryable.ProjectTo<Model>

Comment: Does it include the User in the query? Can you post the code?

Comment: This is the whole project statement: entity.ProjectTo<ResponseModel>().ToList(); where entity is the queryable of the SomeModel type

Comment: What is the content of SomeQueryable?

Comment: I have some service function that gets all elements from a database, I return them as queryable. So this Queryable is nothing but the elements some elements extracted from the database. Now, in order to avoid cicrcular reference exception I should project them to some response model.

Comment: I suspect your query does not include the User property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are you class definitions:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class SomeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SomeModelDetailsResponseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

**Solution 1**

Do your mapping like this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<SomeModel, SomeModelDetailsResponseModel>().AfterMap((b, r) =>
        {
            r.UserName = b.User.FirstName + b.User.LastName;
        });
     });

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var response = mapper.Map<SomeModel, SomeModelDetailsResponseModel>(new SomeModel()
{
    User = new User()
    {
        FirstName = "FN",
        LastName = "LN"
    }
});
```

Since you have your input as `IQueryable<SomeModel>` and you want to project it into `IQueryable<SomeModelDetailsResponseModel>`, then you can do this:

```
var result = q.Select(m => mapper.Map<SomeModel, SomeModelDetailsResponseModel>(m));
```

where `q` is your `IQueryable<SomeModel>` instance.

**Solution 2**

If you want to use `ProjectTo<>`, then initialize your mapper as the following:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<SomeModel, SomeModelDetailsResponseModel>()
        .ForMember(r => r.UserName, c => c.MapFrom(o => o.User.FirstName + o.User.LastName));
});
```

Then, do your projection as this:

```
var result = q.ProjectTo<SomeModelDetailsResponseModel>().ToArray();
```

Where `q` is your `IQueryable<SomeModel>`.

Comment: Any idea how to do that in the CreateMappings method because I do not get the idea with the new SomeModel {User...}

Comment: What is it that you don't get with the new SomeModel{User...}?

Comment: It is an IQueryable I do not see how this is going to be useful in this occasion. I use ProjectTo<>. I see how to do this with a foreach loop. But if I use it then the whole mapping configuration will be useless.

Comment: Why not using Select instead of ProjectTo<>?